# 15.04 - very slow boot

Tags: boot, 15.04

After upgrading to 15.04 , one computer is very, very slow to boot -several minutes, instead of ~20sec.

I do not know if this helps:

```
graphical.target @1min 40.961s
└─multi-user.target @1min 40.961s
 └─kerneloops.service @1min 36.392s +16ms
 └─network-online.target @1min 36.391s
  └─network.target @1min 30.948s
    └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 31.430s +6ms
      └─basic.target @1min 30.414s
        └─sockets.target @1min 30.414s
          └─acpid.socket @1min 30.414s
            └─sysinit.target @1min 30.412s
              └─networking.service @1.941s +49ms
                └─apparmor.service @1.383s +555ms
                  └─local-fs.target @1.381s
                    └─media-andre-6564\x2d3236.mount @2min 17.386s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @1.375s
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @1.328s +41ms
                          └─systemd-fsck-root.service @1.197s +129ms
                            └─system.slice @324ms
                              └─-.slice @323ms

andre@andre-Latitude-E5520:~$ systemd 
Failed to create root cgroup hierarchy: Permission denied
Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
```

Comment: It's still in beta, isn't it?

Comment: Release is tomorrow, so yes.

Comment: I have same problem with Ubuntu 15.04. Very slow boot.

Comment: No not beta, since 16th it was a release candidate, and now it's released.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was caused by bad swap partition reference in `/etc/crypttab`.
It waited 90 seconds before giving up on that.
For some reason swap was defined on an non-existing drive, once the line was deleted, everything works fine.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same error - it was related to the UUIDs in /etc/fstab. I had resized the disk partition, by deleting the swap partition, and then recreating swap. This caused the swap UUID to change.

List the UUIDs with:

```
 sudo blkid
```

And then check/fix any thatdo not match

```
 sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

On the released version 15.04.
I resized the partition, and after that things really slowed down.

```
 10.588140] audit: type=1400 audit(1430119499.379:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=370 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   97.136477] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
 [   97.420519] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 4.3.26_Ubuntu (interface 0x00010004)
 [   97.421318] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
 [   97.436569] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favourite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: @MichaelLindman I believe this is an attempt to answer the question. From what I gather it was a UUID mismatch and the list in /etc/fstab needed to be updated.

Comment: @java4africa you helped me a lot with your answer. How were you *even able* to relete the cgroup message with the solution.