# Ubuntu 15.04 very slow boot

Tags: boot, 15.04

I looked around for answer to my problem, but never find, so I'm asking for help.

> $ uname -a
>
> > Linux Aspire-E1-570 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and

> $ systemd-analyze
>
> > Startup finished in 4.010s (firmware) + 4.277s (loader) + 5.155s (kernel) + 50.863s (userspace) = 1min 4.307s

and

> $ systemd-analyze blame
>
> > ```
> >      26.598s gpu-manager.service
> >      13.898s plymouth-quit-wait.service
> >      13.430s ModemManager.service
> >      12.833s NetworkManager.service
> >      12.191s systemd-udev-settle.service
> >      11.549s accounts-daemon.service
> >      11.484s binfmt-support.service
> >      11.305s systemd-logind.service
> >      11.062s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7542b6f\x2d4b2b\x2d46a1\x2db1a9\x2dbeea0e6
> >      10.840s ondemand.service
> >      10.839s irqbalance.service
> >      10.833s bluetooth.service
> >      10.826s rsyslog.service
> >      10.812s apport.service
> >      10.463s preload.service
> >      10.460s grub-common.service
> >      10.454s systemd-user-sessions.service
> >      10.454s avahi-daemon.service
> >      10.445s thermald.service
> >       6.191s ufw.service
> >       5.975s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> >       5.680s kerneloops.service
> >       5.176s systemd-udevd.service
> > ```

and

> $ systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @50.834s
└─multi-user.target @50.834s
 └─getty.target @50.834s
  └─getty@tty1.service @50.833s
    └─rc-local.service @36.878s +50ms
      └─network.target @36.792s
       └─wpa_supplicant.service @37.252s +232ms
         └─basic.target @23.578s
          └─sockets.target @23.578s
            └─cups.socket @23.577s
              └─sysinit.target @23.551s
                └─networking.service @23.113s +436ms
                  └─apparmor.service @19.125s +3.982s
                    └─local-fs.target @19.117s
                      └─boot-efi.mount @18.879s +235ms
                        └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0230\x2d399C.serv
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @17.701s
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @17.576s +92ms
                              └─systemd-fsck-root.service @17.127s +445ms
                                └─systemd-fsckd.socket @4.274s
                                  └─-.slice @3.913s
```

Can someone help me? Do you need anything more? Thanks

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot ?

Comment: Do you have a very high percentage of your harddrive taken up? I would think this could have a high impact on boot time. Also, is the harddrive a traditional or SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Test out other ubuntu versions like 14.04.3 LTS or 15.10
to see if your problem occurs there also

press F1 during boot/shutdown process to see whats wrong exactly
to your system, and what hangs/taking time