# Ubuntu gnome slow boot (over a minute), 15.04

Tags: boot, gnome, 15.04, gdm

I am experiencing some unusual booting times in my gnome environment. I have ran bootchart and dsmeg but I am not sure what to extract out of it.

Here's the dsmeg log at about the time the timestamps go nuts

```
   14.050672] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[   14.050712] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[   14.050757] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input18
[   14.082924] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input19
[   14.082965] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
[   14.296485] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (5986:055e)
[   14.299281] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input21
[   14.299350] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   14.299352] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   15.808177] EXT4-fs (sda8): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.098723] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   16.116868] systemd-journald[318]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   16.936316] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.139:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=718 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.960605] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.163:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=715 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.034201] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.235:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=711 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.034427] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.235:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=711 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.034618] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.235:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=711 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.034804] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.235:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=711 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.268363] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.471:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.268727] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.471:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.268911] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.471:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="third_party" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.508585] audit: type=1400 audit(1443487935.711:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=714 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  103.380915] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  103.380917] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  103.380922] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  103.477099] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  103.477106] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  103.477110] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  104.817551] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[  104.817573] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[  106.459825] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link up
[  107.261197] bbswitch: version 0.7
[  107.261204] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[  107.261210] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[  107.261231] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  107.261304] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[  107.261313] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[  108.672122] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[  108.704006] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704033] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704046] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704065] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704076] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704088] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704111] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.704123] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  108.724689] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[  111.250635] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[  114.331074] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[  114.332830] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[  114.332832] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[  114.332833] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 9ECN31WW(V1.14), EC unknown
[  114.332834] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo Lenovo Y50-70, model 20378
[  114.380499] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 8-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[  114.380542] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[  114.380618] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[  114.416620] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input22
[  114.418115] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  114.458003] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  114.633546] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
[  114.640667] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
[  124.769979] audit_printk_skb: 30 callbacks suppressed
[  124.769992] audit: type=1400 audit(1443488042.718:22): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/dconf/profile/gdm" pid=1501 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=0
[  128.597071] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[  136.325505] wlan0: authenticate with d8:50:e6:c8:a8:28
[  136.349068] wlan0: send auth to d8:50:e6:c8:a8:28 (try 1/3)
[  136.351498] wlan0: authenticated
[  136.352643] wlan0: associate with d8:50:e6:c8:a8:28 (try 1/3)
[  136.358875] wlan0: RX AssocResp from d8:50:e6:c8:a8:28 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  136.359396] wlan0: associated
[  140.768322] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
```

Also here's my boot chart. It looks like it has a 20 second idle time or something? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E35W.jpg
I can't embed an image because of my reputation so I am leaving an imgur link.

Also, heres the result of systemd-analyze:

```
graphical.target @1min 42.536s
└─multi-user.target @1min 42.535s
  └─getty.target @1min 42.535s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 42.535s
      └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 30.577s +1.277s
        └─basic.target @1min 30.568s
          └─sockets.target @1min 30.568s
            └─acpid.socket @1min 30.568s
              └─sysinit.target @1min 30.525s
                └─networking.service @5.417s +46ms
                  └─apparmor.service @5.250s +165ms
                    └─local-fs.target @5.250s
                      └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @2min 5.982s
                        └─run-user-1000.mount @2min 4.452s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @4.601s
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.597s +3ms
                              └─systemd-fsck-root.service @4.493s +103ms
                                └─systemd-fsckd.socket @434ms
                                  └─-.slice @417ms
```

Comment: My browse does not enlarge the picture enough to gain much from it. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_boot_performance and http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Optimizations/  . I am not aware of any Debian or Ubuntu specific systemd optimization documentation.

Comment: Hey, if you manually zoom in with your mouse wheel or your keyboard shortcut after using the imgur click-zoom you can easily see the image. Also I added some systemd-analyze critical-chain info

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, I had an old entry in my /etc/crypttab with no real partition counterpart.

Same as this question

[15.04 - very slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot)