# Boot slowed down by more than 90sec on upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, upgrade

After I did my last `dist-upgrade` from 15.04 to 15.10 a few days ago, Ubuntu takes a very long time to boot.

I did a lot of research and tried to get all the `dmesg` messages, but I think I lack enough knowledge to get it all.

This is what’s really strange: If I load the previous Ubuntu version from Grub, it also needs takes a long time to boot, which it didn’t previously.

```
[   14.194628] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[  104.096005] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

Where does this 90 seconds come from?

[Hardware with `dmidecode`](http://pastebin.com/2BJfwLHw).

[Latest full `dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/iJHT28JK).

I tried to solve the problem myself. My first guess was the `iwlwifi`, so I installed the latest one from Intel. This had no effect.

I also see a bios bug in the `dmesg`. I haven’t fixed this yet (I don’t have an empty USB stick with me).

I’m not an expert, but the time-consuming-problem seems to be somewhere else.

I thought about problems with the UUIDs in the `fstab` and compared it with `blkid` output. It all fits except the `swap`, so I changed the `fstab`. My swap is on `/dev/sda5`; `fstab` had a UUID for it. `bklid` showed me only a `PARTUUID` for `/dev/sda5` (it showed a UUID for all other partitions). I changed the UUID for swap to the `PARTUUID` in `fstab`, but this had no effect.

sytemd-analyze blame (first 10 lines):

```
  6.281s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  1.028s mysql.service
   331ms dev-sda2.device
   308ms gpu-manager.service
   163ms systemd-localed.service
   160ms ModemManager.service
   126ms accounts-daemon.service
   108ms binfmt-support.service
    91ms systemd-hostnamed.service
    75ms apparmor.service
```

[Latest full `systemd-analyze blame`](http://pastebin.com/ZcPAymgr)

PS: my dualboot gaming-os (win 7) still boots in normal speed, so i'm pretty sure it's not a hardware issue

PPS: thx for editing my bad english

TEMPORARY SOLUTION:
I [switched from systemd back to upstart](http://linuxg.net/replace-systemd-with-upstart-on-ubuntu-15-04-or-an-official-flavor/). Now it boots fast again. But i'm still interested to understand the problem.

Comment: can you post the output (just the firsr 5-10 lines) of **systemd-analyze blame** ?

Comment: Edited my original post;

Comment: try to disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service., should not cause any problem to your system. Take a look: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Enable_NetworkManager_Wait_Online

Comment: Only systemd uses this service, right?

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot EDIT: Nevermind, your `dmesg` seems to point to a different reason.