# Lubuntu 16.04 boot slow (cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored)

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, fstab

After upgrading from Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, the boot takes much longer time. Running `dmesg`, I find one task takes a significantly longer time:

```
cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

Searching on internet, it seems to be a fstab issue. It happens to those who adjust the partitions. But the thing is that I never adjust the partitions during or after the upgrade. Also the result of blkid matches the content of fstab.

Output of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="40F4AB0BF4AB01F0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4de78bef-01"  
/dev/sda2: UUID="909fbd0b-69c1-45a3-b7fc-9bbe122fa7fe" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4de78bef-02"  
/dev/sda3: UUID="a5e6b8bc-14b8-4032-8e01-9dbd8a7893a5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4de78bef-03"  
/dev/sda4: UUID="0471ceb6-79cd-49ad-a708-f9045d092873" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4de78bef-04"
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
UUID=909fbd0b-69c1-45a3-b7fc-9bbe122fa7fe /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1  
UUID=a5e6b8bc-14b8-4032-8e01-9dbd8a7893a5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2  
UUID=0471ceb6-79cd-49ad-a708-f9045d092873 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Can anybody say why it's giving this error message?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same issue, but after I installed a second Linux and configured it to share the swap partition with Ubuntu. Even after I adjusted the `/etc/fstab` file, Ubuntu would need 2 minutes to show the login screen. The command `dmesg` displayed the message `cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored`.

In my `fstab` I found the following entry: `#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`, and that was a hint that there used to exist a cryptswap partition that I probably set up when I installed Ubuntu (I do not remember now).

However, to get rid of the remains of that partition I did the following:
1. `sudo swapoff`
2. `sudo cryptsetup remove /dev/mapper/cryptswap1` (In my case, this file was already deleted)
3. `sudo vim /etc/crypttab`   Here, I found an entry that referred to the non-existing cryptswap. I deleted it.
4. `sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sda4` (In your case, swap is on /dev/sda4)
5. `sudo swapon /dev/sda4`. 
Afterwards, my Ubuntu started normally again. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

My /etc/fstab somehow got a logical volume map (LVM) disk added to it. I don't know how because this is something I have never used on this machine.

```
/dev/mapper/vg_phoebus-lv_swap none swap sw 0 0
```

I used:

```
sudo dmsetup -v table /dev/mapper/vg_phoebus-lv_swap
```

and:

```
ls -lha /dev/mapper
```

to confirm there was no LVM volumes and then I removed that line from /etc/fstab.

There is a handy way to look at what's taking time to boot:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Mostly unrelated but through I would add it here. I also had a problem with powerd on shutdown see this bug report: [powerd takes eternity to boot on pc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/powerd/+bug/1443278)

I disabled it as suggested:

```
sudo systemctl disable powerd.service
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating to 16.04. I found this answer to be very helpful and it solved my problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/614660/319782

Long story short list your UUID's

```
sudo blkid
```

Check for UUID mismatches in /etc/fstab

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

fix mismatches if they exist

```
sudo emacs /etc/fstab
```

then reboot

Comment: As shown in the original post, the result of blkid matches exactly what's inside fstab.

Comment: I only see three drives in the fstab but 4 in the blkid.

Comment: /dev/sda1 is the windows partition and I guess it's never added to fstab, even under lubuntu 14.04

Comment: How do you `fix mismatches if they exist`?  What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Downvoted this answer I'm afraid, as it's not offering any actual help AFAIKT.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts Really? It helped me. I guess you have a different problem. Thanks for stopping by, though.

Comment: @atomSmasher the words "fix mismatches if they exist" is too vague - mismatches in what?

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem (in EC2) because I changed one of the drives (the boot drive) from a solid state drive (SSD) and to a magnetic drive.  I didn't update the /etc/fstab, which showed the mount option as

> defaults,discard

It turns out that the 'discard' option is unique to SSD drives* so doesn't apply to magnetic drives.  I removed the discard option and the message went away.

*http://blog.neutrino.es/2013/howto-properly-activate-trim-for-your-ssd-on-linux-fstrim-lvm-and-dmcrypt/