# Boot taking too long on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, startup

I am having problems with boot time with 16.04. How can I solve it? Can't understand the logs...

Here are the outputs of various commands:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @1min 30.597s
└─lightdm.service @1min 30.395s +201ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 30.195s +57ms
    └─basic.target @1min 30.177s
      └─sockets.target @1min 30.177s
        └─snapd.socket @1min 30.177s +223us
          └─sysinit.target @1min 30.173s
            └─systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service @1.175s +14ms
              └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @587ms
                └─system.slice @87ms
                  └─-.slice @85ms
```

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.146s (firmware) + 6.268s (loader) + 7.608s (kernel) **+ 3min 423ms (userspace)** = 3min 16.447s
```

```
$ systemd-analyze blame 
660ms dev-sda4.device
223ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
205ms accounts-daemon.service
201ms lightdm.service
190ms ModemManager.service
182ms apparmor.service
175ms gpu-manager.service
160ms systemd-logind.service
157ms systemd-rfkill.service
125ms grub-common.service
121ms ondemand.service
119ms apport.service
118ms irqbalance.service
115ms console-setup.service
102ms NetworkManager.service
 98ms upower.service
 92ms speech-dispatcher.service
 85ms systemd-localed.service
 78ms alsa-restore.service
 75ms keyboard-setup.service
 65ms networking.service
 62ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 57ms systemd-user-sessions.service
 57ms systemd-udevd.service
 57ms pppd-dns.service
 51ms systemd-update-utmp.service
 48ms systemd-hostnamed.service
 47ms bluetooth.service
 47ms thermald.service
 44ms udisks2.service
 42ms rsyslog.service
 38ms systemd-timesyncd.service
 38ms avahi-daemon.service
 36ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BE0A\x2dCB90.service
 35ms systemd-journald.service
 34ms snapd.firstboot.service
 34ms wpa_supplicant.service
 32ms resolvconf.service
 25ms plymouth-start.service
 24ms user@1000.service
 23ms systemd-modules-load.service
 20ms polkitd.service
 19ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 15ms colord.service
 14ms dns-clean.service
 14ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
 14ms boot-efi.mount
 13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
```

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="GRUB" UUID="BE0A-CB90" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d8fb4ac0-c0b7-427d-8507-0cf43b27043c"
/dev/sda2: UUID="e3a1dc8a-52d3-4cb4-ab5a-4ecf745a10f5" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="1fcaf589-217b-4846-a6bc-7cbf860aca96"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Operating System" UUID="695f4ae8-e03f-4cf3-bc07-924c4cf57663" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="105224a8-b436-4378-9746-70bc5ebaa77e"
```

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=695f4ae8-e03f-4cf3-bc07-924c4cf57663 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                    none            swap    sw                0       0
UUID=BE0A-CB90  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
UUID=e3a1dc8a-52d3-4cb4-ab5a-4ecf745a10f5 none swap sw 0 1
```

Snippet of `dmseg`:

```
[    8.787728] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   97.902641] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   97.902645] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   97.902651] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
$ fdisk -l
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  233291776 250068991  16777216     8G Linux swap
/dev/sda4    1050624 233291775 232241152 110,8G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Duplicate of 815652.  See the answer for cryptswap cleanup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lubuntu 16.04 boot slow (cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815652/lubuntu-16-04-boot-slow-cgroup-new-mount-options-do-not-match-the-existing-sup)

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/crypttab` Here, I found an entry that referred to the non-existing cryptswap. I deleted it.

Got it from: [Ubuntu 16.04 boot slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815652/lubuntu-16-04-boot-slow-cgroup-new-mount-options-do-not-match-the-existing-sup)