# ubuntu 16.04 slow boot cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock,

Tags: boot, uuid

I followed steps from here [Lubuntu 16.04 boot slow (cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815652/lubuntu-16-04-boot-slow-cgroup-new-mount-options-do-not-match-the-existing-sup) @atomSmasher answer.  But I dont know how to apply the fix.

When I run `sudo blkid`

I get: `/dev/sda1: UUID="cf1434da-f40c-44a7-a91f-1eed360eac29" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000844fb-01"`

Then when I run `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=cf1434da-f40c-44a7-a91f-1eed360eac29 /               ext4         errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=12d3baaf-f6d2-455e-ad35-c7278c0a5729 none            swap    sw
```

What am I supposed to do here?  He mentions: 
`fix mismatches if they exist`
`sudo emacs /etc/fstab`
`then reboot`

But how do I `FIX` the mismatch?

**update**; when i run `dmesg` you can see a time gap:

```
[    7.763395] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    7.763397] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.763399] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   97.165431] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   97.278868] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   97.278871] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   97.278876] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   97.504574] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   97.515666] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   97.582966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

the result from `lbsk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 238.5G  0 part /
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't post the complete output of `sudo blkid`, and what we don't see is the UUID for the swap partition. We need to also check that they match. Also give us the output of `lsblk`. Please give us a current-window-only screenshot of gparted.

Comment: It looks like your UUID's in /etc/fstab do match `sudo blkid`, I would suggest trying a different answer. It looks like another possible solution is a nonexistent swap in /etc/crypttab, so please post the output of `sudo cat /etc/crypttab`

Comment: thank you @EvanChen, when I run this  I get `cat: /etc/crypttab: No such file or directory`

Comment: also the the full out put from `sudo blkid` was this 1 line `/dev/sda1: UUID="cf1434da-f40c-44a7-a91f-1eed360eac29" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000844fb-01"`

Comment: I'm still hoping that you'll put up a current-window-only screenshot of gparted. I asked 24 hours ago. I still think that your problem is with your swap partition, but I have to SEE it. Please advise.

Comment: @heynnema updated the question, posted the result from `lbsk`

Comment: As I suspected. You're missing your swap partition. Please put up the screenshot that I've requested twice.

Comment: gparted is up now @heynnema

Comment: Thank you, but please post an image of the entire gparted window (current-window-only in screenshot app).

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48530/discussion-between-t-q-and-heynnema).

Comment: Didn't see you in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sudo blkid` shows only one partition, the problem might be caused by not having a swap as listed in /etc/fstab.

Try commenting out your swap:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
2. Add a "#" in front of the second UUID line so it looks like this: `# UUID=12d3baaf-f6d2-455e-ad35-c7278c0a5729 none`
3. Save

At this point, you will not encounter the error anymore, but you do not have a swap partition or swapfile. Depending on what you do on your computer, you may want to add a swapfile.

As outlined by https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-swap-creating-file.html

1. Become root with `sudo -s`
2. Decide how large you want your swapfile to be. If you use hibernate, then make your swapfile at least as large your ram. If you run a lot of ram-intensive applications like video editing software make your swap 2GB-8GB. If you just run light web browsing, 512MB-1GB will do, but unused swap space won't hurt besides using more disk space.
3. Open a calculator, do 1024*[Desired swap size in GB]
4. Back at the terminal, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=y` where y is the number from the calculator
5. Change permissions of the swapfile: `chmod 0600 /swapfile`
6. Setup the swapfile: `mkswap /swapfile`
7. Add the swapfile entry to /etc/fstab `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
8. Add the line `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0`
9. Save, then reboot

Comment: The more correct step #1 would be `sudo -i gedit /etc/fstab`.

Comment: `sudo -i` will make almost no difference for editing /etc/fstab, adding the `-i` argument merely adds complexity to the command at almost no gain

Comment: @tq this is not a complete solution. Right now you have NO swap file, and with 8G RAM, you need a swap file.

Comment: @EvanChen did you mean to add the line `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0` at the end of file `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yes, you add that line at the end of /etc/fstab, on a new line

Comment: I am getting ` (gedit:7745): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported`

Comment: also: dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=4096
dd: failed to open '/swapfile': Text file busy

Comment: maybe it worked, when i `swapon --show` i get NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   4G   0B   -1

Comment: Based on the output of `swapon --show` it did work. The gedit error should not be a problem and the dd error means there's already a swapfile in use there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message and symptom appear in Ubuntu 16.10.

The problem turned out to be a swap partition assigned to a non-existent disk partition.

I commented out the swap partition in /etc/fstab and the boot time dropped to the normal amount of time.

I did not need to assign a swap partition, I've got 16gb of ram.