# Slow boot on SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, services

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with new SSD (4 months old), I had boot time like 5-8 seconds.

But some time ago my boot time increased to around 1 minute.

Can you help me please what is the problem and how to fix it?

Result from `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @1min 36.464s
└─multi-user.target @1min 36.464s
  └─esets.service @1min 30.419s +6.044s
    └─network.target @1min 30.415s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 30.781s +34ms
        └─basic.target @1min 30.176s
          └─sockets.target @1min 30.176s
            └─snapd.socket @1min 30.174s +1ms
              └─sysinit.target @1min 30.171s
                └─apparmor.service @749ms +403ms
                  └─local-fs.target @728ms
                    └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 52.381s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @724ms
                        └─lvm2-monitor.service @138ms +585ms
                          └─lvm2-lvmetad.service @206ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @130ms
                              └─-.slice @114ms
```

Result from `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
  6.044s esets.service
  5.507s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  3.673s apt-daily.service
  1.845s dev-sda1.device
  1.144s snapd.service
   875ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
   826ms ufw.service
   585ms lvm2-monitor.service
   403ms apparmor.service
   291ms ModemManager.service
   265ms console-setup.service
   260ms binfmt-support.service
   246ms accounts-daemon.service
   245ms dev-loop0.device
   226ms dev-loop1.device
   203ms systemd-logind.service
   202ms dev-loop2.device
   200ms dev-loop5.device
   199ms dev-loop3.device
   192ms grub-common.service
   185ms upower.service
   184ms dev-loop4.device
   169ms irqbalance.service
   163ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   163ms ondemand.service
   158ms systemd-rfkill.service
   157ms networking.service
   141ms user@1000.service
   128ms qemu-kvm.service
   126ms virtualbox.service
   125ms NetworkManager.service
   124ms keyboard-setup.service
   115ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   115ms pppd-dns.service
   112ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
   111ms packagekit.service
    99ms thermald.service
    97ms systemd-journald.service
    92ms bluetooth.service
    88ms avahi-daemon.service
    85ms rsyslog.service
    77ms snap-core-4917.mount
    71ms snap-core-5145.mount
    66ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-27.mount
    66ms snapd.seeded.service
    62ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-13.mount
    59ms systemd-udevd.service
    58ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
    52ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5-16.mount
    52ms systemd-modules-load.service
    51ms snap-core-5328.mount
    47ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
    41ms gpu-manager.service
    40ms resolvconf.service
    39ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
    34ms wpa_supplicant.service
    33ms polkitd.service
    32ms udisks2.service
    31ms alsa-restore.service
    30ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
    28ms plymouth-quit.service
    26ms dev-hugepages.mount
    23ms systemd-timesyncd.service
    22ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
    20ms kmod-static-nodes.service
    18ms systemd-remount-fs.service
    18ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
    18ms rtkit-daemon.service
    17ms systemd-update-utmp.service
    16ms dev-mqueue.mount
    16ms systemd-sysctl.service
    16ms plymouth-start.service
    15ms systemd-journal-flush.service
    14ms plymouth-read-write.service
     9ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     9ms ureadahead-stop.service
     8ms sddm.service
     8ms systemd-random-seed.service
     7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     6ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
     5ms sys-kernel-config.mount
     5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
     4ms rc-local.service
     4ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
     4ms setvtrgb.service
     1ms snapd.socket
```

**UPDATE:** My problem solved: [15.04 - very slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot)

Comment: Did you read that output to figure out which task is taking so much time? Or are you asking how to read the output?

Comment: My problem solved: https://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot